# Add column to data frame to show the most recent description

Tags: r, dplyr

I have spent hours today to find a solution to this, there are similar threads out there but not quite what I need.

Dataset:

```
Year          <- c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021)
Term          <- c("2019_T1", "2020_T1", "2021_T1", "2019_T1", "2020_T1", "2020_T2", "2021_T1", "2021_T2")
Code          <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Description   <- c("Desc1","Desc1","Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc2", "Desc2", "Desc2_NotRecent","Desc2_Recent")
```

This produces a table as follows:

```
  Year    Term Code     Description
1 2019 2019_T1    1           Desc1
2 2020 2020_T1    1           Desc1
3 2021 2021_T1    1           Desc1
4 2019 2019_T1    2           Desc2
5 2020 2020_T1    2           Desc2
6 2020 2020_T2    2           Desc2
7 2021 2021_T1    2 Desc2_NotRecent
8 2021 2021_T2    2    Desc2_Recent
```

Question:
How to add a column to show the most recent Description for each Code.

I will need to find the most recent based on the Term. Perhaps this can be accomplished by a simple sort first, apologies I have not figured this out.

Its important its the most recent Term value. Here, the most recent Term is 2021_T2. If the first value is selected, it could be an old description and confuse stakeholders.

Outcome I need:

```
  Year    Term Code     Description  Most_Recent
1 2019 2019_T1    1           Desc1        Desc1
2 2020 2020_T1    1           Desc1        Desc1
3 2021 2021_T1    1           Desc1        Desc1
4 2019 2019_T1    2           Desc2 Desc2_Recent
5 2020 2020_T1    2           Desc2 Desc2_Recent
6 2020 2020_T2    2           Desc2 Desc2_Recent
7 2021 2021_T1    2 Desc2_NotRecent Desc2_Recent
8 2021 2021_T2    2    Desc2_Recent Desc2_Recent
```

Really grateful for all of the help. Edited to include simple solution from Robin Gertenbach.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  dplyr:: mutate(Most_Recent = dplyr::last(Description, Term))
```

Comment: tip: you don't need to ``cbind`` when you are using ``data.frame`` - it will coerce to a matrix first and possibly change the type of your columns with you noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter solution, no joins or conditionals

```
df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Most_Recent = last(Description, Term))
```

Comment: I get an error trying to run this: Error in checkHT(n, dx <- dim(x)) : 
  invalid 'n' - must have length one when dim(x) is NULL, got 8 (not sure how to highlight this as code in a comment!)

Comment: Is that on the dataset you provided or on a different one? These are all dplyr functions and I get the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is the same one. Weird! I cleared the environment and ran it again and got the same error.

Comment: Do you maybe have a namespace conflict from where you are getting `last` from? e.g. Does `?last` give you the `dplyr::last` documentation?

Comment: I have it in both data.table and dplyr so I called dplyr:: mutate(Most_Recent = last(Description, Term)), I still got this error: invalid 'n' - must have length one when dim(x) is NULL, got 3

Comment: I am being a Numpty. I think I just need to group_by on both Code and Term for this to work! Checking now.

Comment: Using `data.table::last` I get a different, error. Have you tried explicitly qualifying all namespaces like `dplyr::mutate(Most_Recent = dplyr::last(Description, Term))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237050/discussion-between-keelin-and-robin-gertenbach).

Comment: This is a really elegant solution and I just had to call dplyr first.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** after clarification: See comments:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  separate(Term, c("Year", "T"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(T = parse_number(T),
         Most_recent = ifelse(Year == max(Year) & T == max(T), Description, NA)
         ) %>% 
  fill(Most_recent, .direction = "up")
```

output:

```
  Term    Code  Year      T Description     Most_recent 
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>           <chr>       
1 2019_T1 1     2019      1 Desc1           Desc1       
2 2020_T1 1     2020      1 Desc1           Desc1       
3 2021_T1 1     2021      1 Desc1           Desc1       
4 2019_T1 2     2019      1 Desc2           Desc2_Recent
5 2020_T1 2     2020      1 Desc2           Desc2_Recent
6 2020_T2 2     2020      2 Desc2           Desc2_Recent
7 2021_T1 2     2021      1 Desc2_NotRecent Desc2_Recent
8 2021_T2 2     2021      2 Desc2_Recent    Desc2_Recent
```

**First answer:**
Here is `tidyverse` way how you could get your result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year),
         Most_recent = ifelse(Year == max(Year), Description, NA)
         ) %>% 
  fill(Most_recent, .direction = "up")
```

output:

```
   Year Term    Code  Description  Most_recent 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>       
1  2019 2019_T1 1     Desc1        Desc1       
2  2020 2020_T1 1     Desc1        Desc1       
3  2021 2021_T1 1     Desc1        Desc1       
4  2019 2019_T1 2     Desc2        Desc2_Recent
5  2020 2020_T1 2     Desc2        Desc2_Recent
6  2020 2020_T2 2     Desc2        Desc2_Recent
7  2021 2021_T2 2     Desc2_Recent Desc2_Recent
```

Comment: This is great if descriptions are all the same in a year, but if there are two descriptions in a year across two terms it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok. Please see my update. Now it should work!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

Year <- c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021)
Term <- c("2019_T1", "2020_T1", "2021_T1", "2019_T1", "2020_T1", "2020_T2", "2021_T2")
Code <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Description <- c("Desc1", "Desc1", "Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc2", "Desc2", "Desc2_Recent")

df <- data.frame(cbind(Year, Term, Code, Description))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Year = Year %>% as.integer())

most_recent_descriptions <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  arrange(-Year) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  transmute(
    Code,
    Most_Recent = Description
  )

df %>%
  left_join(most_recent_descriptions)
#> Joining, by = "Code"
#>   Year    Term Code  Description  Most_Recent
#> 1 2019 2019_T1    1        Desc1        Desc1
#> 2 2020 2020_T1    1        Desc1        Desc1
#> 3 2021 2021_T1    1        Desc1        Desc1
#> 4 2019 2019_T1    2        Desc2 Desc2_Recent
#> 5 2020 2020_T1    2        Desc2 Desc2_Recent
#> 6 2020 2020_T2    2        Desc2 Desc2_Recent
#> 7 2021 2021_T2    2 Desc2_Recent Desc2_Recent
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, I just edited to add an update on different descriptions by Term, I'll try the solutions by year.

Comment: My data may have two descriptions in a given term, is there a way to sort it on Term?

Comment: Imagine you have a description not only per Year but per month. Then you can do `arrange(-Year, -Month)` to get the description with the highest month of that year.

Comment: Thanks @danloo, I dont appear to have dont that right using the pipe arrange(-Year, -Term) % I get an error: Error in -Term : invalid argument to unary operator. So it would appear it needs a date for this to work.

Comment: Remove the `-` from `Term`. Arrangement is done ascendying by default. Negating results in descending search. This only works for numbers. But you can do sth like `arrange(desc(Term))`

Answer (score 1):

Split the `Term` value in two columns as `'Year'` and `'Term'`, `arrange` the data by `Year` and `Term` and for each `Code` get the `last` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(Term, c('Year', 'Term'), sep = '_', convert = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(Code, Year, order(gtools::mixedorder(Term))) %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Most_Recent = last(Description)) %>%
  ungroup

#   Code  Year Term  Description     Most_Recent 
#  <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>           <chr>       
#1     1  2019 T1    Desc1           Desc1       
#2     1  2020 T1    Desc1           Desc1       
#3     1  2021 T1    Desc1           Desc1       
#4     2  2019 T1    Desc2           Desc2_Recent
#5     2  2020 T1    Desc2           Desc2_Recent
#6     2  2020 T2    Desc2           Desc2_Recent
#7     2  2021 T1    Desc2_NotRecent Desc2_Recent
#8     2  2021 T2    Desc2_Recent    Desc2_Recent
```

If you want the `Year` and `Term` values in one column again you may add `unite` to do the above chain.

```
...ungroup %>% unite(Term, Year, Term)
```